# Showing current location in my iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, xcode4.5, routes

I am implementing the route directions from my current location to some destination location.

When I enter in a specific page, my application crashes. But if I run the app again, it shows the route directions.

I found out the problem is that the first time, current location is showing as `0.00000,0.00000` coordinates. The second time I launch the app, current location is showing up correctly.

What is going wrong? 
I want to get my current position correctly at first time.

I am writing the code on below. Once please check it out and let me know the where is the problem in my code

```
#import "MapWithRoutesViewController.h"
#import "TFSViewController.h"

@implementation MapWithRoutesViewController

@synthesize locationManager,lat,lon;

- (void) updateCurrentLabel {
    NSObject *latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude];
    NSObject *longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];

    locationlable.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Current Location: %@,%@", latitude, longitude];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [self getCurrentLocation];
    [super viewDidLoad]; 
}

-(void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    [self updateCurrentLabel]; 
}

-(void) getCurrentLocation {
    MapView* mapView = [[[MapView alloc] initWithFrame:
                         CGRectMake(0, 90, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)] autorelease];      [self.view
addSubview:mapView];
    Place* home = [[[Place alloc] init] autorelease];


    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;

    if (locationManager==NO) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Location Service Disabled"
                                                        message:@"To re-enable, please go to Settings and turn on Location Service for
this app."
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    } else {
        //        if (locationManager==NO)
        //            [mapView.lo addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"location"
        // options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew|NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld)
        // context:nil];
    }

    locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;

    [locationManager setPausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically:YES];
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];


    CLLocation *Loc = [locationManager location];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [Loc coordinate];

    NSObject *latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude];
    NSObject *longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];


    NSLog(@"lat,lon %@%@",latitude,longitude);

    home.name = @"";
home.description = @"";
home.latitude = coordinate.latitude;
home.longitude = coordinate.longitude; 

    Place* office = [[[Place alloc] init] autorelease];
office.name = @"";
office.description = @"";
office.latitude = 22.0000;
    office.longitude = 88.0008;

    [mapView showRouteFrom:home to:office];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated. 
}

-(IBAction)back:(id)sender{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(IBAction)tfs:(id)sender{
    TFSViewController *tfs = [[TFSViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"TFSViewController" bundle:nil];

    [self presentViewController:tfs animated:YES completion:nil];
}

@end
```

Comment: Are you checking in simulator ?

Comment: Show some code efforts on it. Where you are implementing location update, and assigning map properties? Specially in which view controller method you are implementing these code as "viewDidload" , "viewWillAppeare" ?  Please answer these questions. Because there are so many possibilities of errors.

Comment: show your code ......

Comment: Show your code please!

Comment: I have posted my code once please check it out this

Comment: Once please give me the solution..

Answer (score 1):

The trouble is you're making the location manager and then expecting it to have a location a few micro seconds later. You should be setting the location manager's delegate and then waiting for it to be called. When LM has a location it will call didUpdateLocation and you can use that to call updateCurrentLabel

Answer (score 1):

You should use delegate method -locationManager:didUpdateLocations: to get the locations. CLLocationManager takes few seconds to establish a GPS connection and determine the current location.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CLLocationManagerDelegate/locationManager:didUpdateLocations:

You could also use CLLocation's horizontalAccuracy property to check the accuracy of the location to determine if you want to use the value or discard it.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CLLocation